Windows Explorer crashes from "Group by Type" + List view (Windows 10)
I keep all of my "active" files on my Desktop. They can accumulate sometimes, so to view them in a more organized manner, I normally open a Windows Explorer window with List view and group by file type.
For some reason the past few days whenever I open Windows Explorer and navigate to Desktop, where the default view is List / group by file type, that singular window freezes. I can open new windows that work, I can still use my taskbar, etc. But that one window is now frozen.
If I open the Desktop folder through another means, where the default view isn't List / group by file type, it also doesn't freeze. However it does freeze when I change the view to List / group by file type. Details / group by file type works fine, List / ungrouped works fine, but List / group by file type freezes.
I've had this happen before, but I don't recall what the problem or solution was. This time around, I've restarted, I've installed all updates, I've tried shutting down some unnecessary processes, but no success with any of those.
Anybody know what's going on? Or at least how I can reset my Desktop view so it's not locked into the List / group by file type view?

Explorer is deeply integrated into Windows itself. If there is an issue with Explorer, first thing is try repair with SFC and DISM, https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e  and if that fails to fix the issue, reinstall WIndows 10 from ISO, keeping files.

From another forum, I took the suggestion to move all of the files to another folder, and it fixed it. I moved about 90% of the files to another folder and it worked. Ironically when I set that folder to the same view settings as my Desktop, it worked fine.
Anybody know what might be the explanation for that? Is there a chance of some file / OS corruption? I did an extended SMART scan on my SSD and it all looks normal, if I'm interpreting correctly.

It is almost 100% caused by a third party shell extension.  See this.  It is a context menu handler here but the cause and mechanism are the same.
